# Add to list if string not present in cell value, break and start new list if present?

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to iterate over a column in Excel and check if a string is present. If the string is present, I want to reset the list to `[]` and repeat the process. Spent too many hours on this and I can't seem to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Example data:

```
Open Ended Schemes(Balanced)    

Aditya Birla Sun Life Mutual Fund   

120518  Aditya Birla Sun Life Equity Hybrid'95 Fund - Direct Plan-Dividend
120517  Aditya Birla Sun Life Equity Hybrid'95 Fund - Direct Plan-Growth


Open Ended Schemes(Debt Scheme - Banking and PSU Fund)  

Axis Mutual Fund    

128953  Axis Banking & PSU Debt Fund - Bonus Option
117447  Axis Banking & PSU Debt Fund - Daily Dividend Option
```

Code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import os
wb = load_workbook('m.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

keys = ['1', '2']
m_dict = {}
scheme_codes = []
for g in groups[0:2]:
    for row in ws.iter_rows('A{}:A{}'.format(ws.min_row +1, ws.max_row)):
        # scheme_codes = []
        for cell in row:
            if cell.value != None:
                if 'Schemes' in cell.value:
                    print('Found Schemes' + str(cell.value))
                    scheme_codes=[]
                    break
                else:
                    scheme = cell.value

                    scheme_codes.append(scheme)
            m_dict[g] = scheme_codes
```

I only get 1 item per scheme, I have tried various ways of doing this and either it just goes all the way through the `rows`. The file has 18000 rows.

Expected output

{1:[All items before first repeat of 'schemes' in 'A' column], 2:[All items before 2nd repeat of 'schemes' in 'A' column]

Right now when I run the code, I get a len(scheme_codes) = 8069 which is wrong as far as I can see. The first list should be near 80 items.

Comment: what is the issue? expected output/output you're getting? of course a [mcve] would be the best (not easy with excel as input, though)

Comment: `m_dict[g] = scheme_codes.copy()`

Comment: @SebastianLoehner gives a `list indices must be integers, not str error.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre added file and expected output.

Comment: have you tried to swap both lines: `scheme_codes = []
for g in groups[0:2]:` so the list assignment is within the first loop?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre just did, now: len(m_dict['1']) is 15068, I believe it just skipped the empty rows and the ones where 'scheme' was present.

Comment: to be honest, I can't help you right now. a further step would be to work from a small csv file that you can paste in your question. Now you would get answers :)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre update the question with sample data. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exactly what your asking for, it actually provides some additional information...

It gives you a dict of dicts holding a set of tuples of scheme_code and scheme_names, like:

`{scheme: {sub_scheme : {(code, name), (code, name), ...}}}`

If you really only need the top level scheme and it's codes, you should be able to simplify it.
Just remove one level of defaultdict and use `scheme_codes[scheme].add(cell.value)` instead...

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
import os

from collections import defaultdict

wb = load_workbook("mfcodes.xlsx")
ws = wb.active

scheme_codes = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(set))

scheme = 'N/A'
sub_scheme = 'N/A'
for row in ws[f'A{ws.min_row}:B{ws.max_row}']:
    cell = row[0]
    if not cell.value:
        continue

    if 'Schemes' in cell.value:
        scheme = cell.value
    else:
        if not cell.value.isdigit():
            sub_scheme = cell.value
        else:
            scheme_codes[scheme][sub_scheme].add((cell.value, row[1].value))

print(repr(next(iter(scheme_codes.items()))))
```

Output:

```
{'Open Ended Schemes(Balanced)' :
    {'Aditya Birla Sun Life Mutual Fund': {('120518', "Aditya Birla Sun Life Equity Hybrid'95 Fund - Direct Plan-Dividend"),
                                           ('120517', "Aditya Birla Sun Life Equity Hybrid'95 Fund - Direct Plan-Growth"),
                                           ('103154', "Aditya Birla Sun Life Equity Hybrid'95 Fund - Regular Plan-Dividend"),
                                           ('103155', "Aditya Birla Sun Life Equity Hybrid'95 Fund - Regular Plan-Growth"),
                                           ('131671', 'Aditya Birla Sun Life Balanced Advantage Fund - Direct Plan - Dividend Option'),
                                           ('131670', 'Aditya Birla Sun Life Balanced Advantage Fund - Direct Plan - Growth Option'),
                                           ('131665', 'Aditya Birla Sun Life Balanced Advantage Fund - Regular Plan - Dividend Option'),
                                           ('131666', 'Aditya Birla Sun Life Balanced Advantage Fund - Regular Plan - Growth Option')},
    'Baroda Pioneer Mutual Fund': {('125112', 'Baroda Pioneer Balance Fund - Plan A - Bonus Option'),
                                   ('101913', 'BARODA PIONEER BALANCE FUND - Plan A - Dividend Option'),
                                   ('101912', 'BARODA PIONEER BALANCE FUND - Plan A - Growth Option'),
                                   ('119325', 'BARODA PIONEER BALANCE FUND - Plan B (Direct) - Dividend Option'),
                                   ('119326', 'BARODA PIONEER BALANCE FUND - Plan B (Direct) - Growth Option')},
    # et cetera ...
    }
}
```

By the way: The first scheme has 67 codes...

Comment: Thanks a ton @SebastianLoehner